# menu item in plugin for outlook using c# VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am trying to create a plugin for outlook using c# VSTO. When I click the "From" button in Outlook in a message, a drop down list appears. I need to add some additional entries to this dropdown list. The MailItem class itself provides many features, but I have not found a way to do what I need to do. Please advise me on how I can do this

Answer (score 0):

The list of extra addresses displayed by the "From" drop-down is stored in the accounts' profile section. You can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click `IOlkAccountManager` button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, double click on your default account, in `IOlkAccount` window right click on the `PROP_ACCT_PREFERENCES_UID` property, select `IMAPISession::OpenProfileSection`. In the `IProfSect` window, select the (`0x0483, PT_MV_UNICODE`) property.

It is accessible through Extended MAPI only (which means only C++ or Delphi, no C#, or [ProfMan](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) in [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) - I am also its author).

Since profile sections are stored in the registry on the MAPI profile basis, you can try to modify the relevant registry values, but it is of course not documented or supported by Microsoft in any way.

[image]